# assertSee failed due to whitespaces in html code

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-blade

In my blade, I have a button:

```
<a
     href="/customer/member/delete/{{ $member->id }}"
     class="btn btn-secondary delete-button"
>
          Delete
</a>
```

And I want to test it:

```
$this->view->assertSee('<a href="/customer/member/delete/1" class="btn btn-secondary delete-button">Delete</a>');
```

How can I ignore whitespaces in the test? A tried: trim and string_replace, but they have not solved the problem.

Comment: I think the question is, why would you structure your blade like that?

Comment: @geertjanknapen that is a normal formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
use Illuminate\Testing\Assert as PHPUnit;

    /**
     * Assert that the given string is contained within the rendered component without whitespaces.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Testing\TestComponent  $haystack
     * @param  string  $needle
     * @param  bool  $escape
     * @return $this
     */
    public function assertSeeWithoutWhitespaces($haystack, $needle, $escape = true)
    {
        $value = $escape ? e($needle) : $needle;

        $value = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/\> /', '>', $value);
        $value = preg_replace('/ </', '<', $value);

        $withoutWhitespaces = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $haystack->render());
        $withoutWhitespaces = preg_replace('/\> /', '>', $withoutWhitespaces);
        $withoutWhitespaces = preg_replace('/ </', '<', $withoutWhitespaces);

        PHPUnit::assertStringContainsString((string) $value, $withoutWhitespaces);

        return $this;
    }
```

And you can use like this:

```php
$this->assertSeeWithoutWhitespaces(
    $view,
    '<a href="/customer/member/delete/1" class="btn btn-secondary delete-button">Delete</a>',
    false
);
```

Now you can use whitespaces in your blade file and in your test string too.

You can extend preg_replace rules as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can split to strings and use `false` like second arguments to NOT escape:

It works from Laravel 7+

```
$strings=[
    '<a',
    'href="/customer/member/delete/1"',
    'class="btn btn-secondary delete-button"',
    '>',  // not strictly necessary, can be removed
    'Delete',
    '</a>'
];

$this->view->assertSeeInOrder($strings, false);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the first `>` or is it not necessary?

Comment: @matiaslauriti In my opinion it isn't strictly necessary, but if we want to add it, we can do in a separate array's item.